# How to make Django url template with variable find the correct url

Tags: python, html, django

In my urls.py I have:

```
    path('experiments/charts/<str:part_tag>/', ExpViews.bokehChart,         name='part_tag')
```

I'd like to pass a string argument "part_tag" to the function bokehChart.

and I'm trying to give the "path_tag" string variable some values as follows:

```
               {% for part in parts %}
                        <ul class="list=group">
                            {% for datapoint in part.datapoints %}
                             <a href="{% url 'part_tag' part.tag %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success"> {{datapoint}} </a>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                {% endfor %}
```

I get the following error on my webpage:

```
Reverse for 'part_tag' not found. 'part_tag' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I know similar questions have been asked, but I can't get it to work in my case.

Comment: Can you please send the view in the question and also check that views properly addressed in the url patterns.

Comment: Do you set `app_name` in your `urls.py`? For example, if you have `app_name = 'charts'`, then the tag should be `{% url 'charts:part_tag' part.tag %}`.